# Tesseract function with no implementation

Tags: c++, function, implementation, tesseract

I am trying to create a project using Tesseract in something other than Visual Studio but there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to go about doing this.

The problem I am at now is that file scanutils.cpp calls a function open(char *, int, mode_t) and this isn't defined anywhere.  Is this possibly a Unix function that slipped by or should be located somewhere on my machine?

Thank you.

Edit:  I have found that the open function is including using the fcntl.h file in Unix, but the version of it that I have (C++ Builder) does not include the open function.  I could just define teh open function in my own file as it is in Unix, but that seems a little reckless.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` is a Posix function that usually wraps the `open` system call in conforming systems. This is a rather "low-level" function that is very platform specific.

The portable C function that provides the equivalent functionality is `fopen()`, in the sense that the result of `open()` is the same as `FILE * fp = fopen(...); int fd = fileno(fp);` -- here `fd` is the integer returned by the underlying `open()` call.

The standard C functions `fwrite()` and `fread()` map to Posix functions `read()` and `write()`, by the way.

Try to stick with standard C functions and `FILE*` data structures as much as possible for maximum portability. If necessary, you can always obtain the Posix file descriptor via `fileno()`.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  The code was using the O_CREATE, O_TRUNC, and O_WRONLY flags and I believe that fopen does the same by default.

Comment: @user912447: Not quite. `fopen()` has a standard set of flags (which you can look up in the manual), which *correspond* to certain `open` flags. But `open` offers a much greater and more fine-tuned set of flags for all sorts of Posix-specific behaviour. Again, check the manual, `man 2 open`.

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft tools, the function `open()` is replaced with `_open()`, defined in `io.h`. [Here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) you can find more information about  it.

Answer (score 0):

`open()` is a standard UNIX function.

Comment: With no implementation in Windows?  I ask because typically the tesseract code that is unix only is wrapped by #ifdef and offers a Windows alternative.  Otherwise it wouldn't compile in Visual Studio which I know that it does.